# Invocation delay of using a local function in parent vs. forked child process? C

Tags: c, fork

I'm having a tough time producing a scenario that will display a time difference between invocation of a simple local function vs. the same function but within a child process.  The particular function I'm testing shows no difference (time = 0) for the difftime(x,y) function for both the local function and the child process.  Can someone generalize potential time differences in these two methods of doing the same thing?

As a side note, I tried doing each task 1000 times and then dividing time by 1000, but even then the time returned is 0.  For example, I have:

```
time(&start);    
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
  reply[i] = my_channel.send_request("hello");
}
time(&end);
time_req_1 = difftime(end,start);
```

And time returned for "time_req_1" = 0.
I only put this code segment in just in case I've done something incorrect.

Comment: The standard `time()` function has a 1 second resolution.  You need to investigate sub-second timers (on POSIX, `clock_gettime()` and `gettimeofday()`, for example -- nanosecond and microsecond resolution, respectively).  Consider `clock()` for portability, but not very fine resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember that the resolution for `time` is in seconds. A common way to time e.g. a function call is to use [`clock`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock):

```
clock_t start_time = clock();

some_lengthy_function_call();

clock_t end_time = clock();

printf("Elapsed time: %.02f seconds\n",
       (double) (end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

**Edit:** If you want even better accuracy and resolution than `clock` can provide, see the comment by Jonathan Leffler to your question.

Comment: Although `clock()` is standard C, and hence probably the most portable sub-second timer, it also typically has a resolution of 1/60 or 1/100 of a second, which is not all that fine (though it is a good step up -- or is it a step down? -- from 1 second resolution).

Answer (score 1):

On most machines with most OS's, time is only accurate to one second.  For only 1000 iterations,  you'll need to find a more accurate time function on your architecture.

A relatively portable interface is [`clock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) .  The last time I tried it under Windows with MSVC, the accuracy was 18ms.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, you need to make sure that after the fork call, you have not called `exec`.

In your second part, well... its running too fast for `difftime` Try using `gettimeofday()` it gives you upto microseconds